# Display an img in a div at cursor position when I click

Tags: image, onclick, display

I'm looking for a way to display an image in a div everytime I click in said div. No button, simply a defined space in a div.

For every new click, a new image would appear,

I have no idea how I could make this possible, probably with js but that would be out of my range...

Thanks have a nice one !

I tried a few options I could fine online but they all came with a button option, I'm really keen on only using the cursor